# Implement a simple game in Java (Graphics-related)

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I am new to game programming in Java, especially on the graphics front, hence I would like to seek some advice on how to implement the following game graphically in Java.

The game is very simple, it displays a square which is further divided into a 2x2 boxes, and the game playing is to put a total of 44 chips into these 4 boxes, and the user should be able to drag and drop the chips from one box to another.

That's it! My questions:

1. is there ready-made library I can use for drawing the square consists of the 4 boxes as well as the chips?
2. if the answer to 1) is no, then is there any tutorial I can follow to program them myself?
3. How to implement the drag and drop part graphically?

Many thanks.

Comment: Should probably be moved to gamedev.stackexchange.  Though there's a similar question already that could provide an answer: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/2d-game-dev-and-java-other-possibilities-than-opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chips can be represented by an Icon added to a JLabel.

Squares can be represented by a JPanel.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html). There are other section of interest as well: How to Use Panels, Using Layout Managers, How to Write a MouseListener, The section on drag and drop maybe.

Comment: that's very helpful to get me started. just a quick follow-up question: presumably you add those JLabels (representing chips) to a JPanel (representing a box), does that mean I have to make sure each of the 4 boxes is big enough to accommodate 44 chips (in the extreme case)?

Comment: I really really would not recommend using JLabel for this, or any game. It's massively slow and has a lot of limitations.

Comment: @skyork, Use a GridLayout to hold the labels.

Comment: @Eli, read the game description again. The user drags Icons from square to square. Its not a shootem up game with bullets and stuff flying all around.

Comment: Yes, but they can do the same thing with less work in the proper fashion, so that if they wanted to add particle effects or prettier animations or whatever, they would be set to go. Might as well learn it the right way first, no?

Comment: @Eli, Sorry, it is LESS code and cleaner code to use JLabels for the drag and drop. You don't have to worry about custom paining or hit detection when you start dragging the mouse. All you worry about is moving the icon from one label to another. I use the tool that is appropriate for the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a Canvas and override paint(Graphics g) and draw your various elements using that. Then you can call repaint() with a timer or a game loop.

```
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas
{
    public void gameLoop()
    {
        //Don't do it this way, this is just a quick example.
        //Instead look up better game loop options.
        while (true)
        {
            repaint(); //automatically calls paintComponent
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }

    //Put all the stuff that gets drawn in here.
    //@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < chips.size(); i++)
        {
            chips.get(i).draw(g);
        }
    }
}

public class Chip
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BROWN);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. Read the game description again. This is not a game that requires a game loop. Also a Canvas doesn't have a paintComponent() method.

Comment: Correct on paintComponent, my mistake. That would be if you were overriding JPanel or something similar. However, I don't think you're justified in giving me -1, my point is still very valid. You are teaching skyork to use Swing elements to make a game, when he should be using Graphics if he wants any sort of flexibility. Use Swing for applications, and Graphics or OpenGL for games.

Comment: Again, this is NOT the type of game that requires a "game loop". It is a simple game that involves users dragging components from one square to another. Just because the user calls this a "grapics game" does not make it one in the context that you are trying to promote.